# Cannot link posts on blog for github

Tags: html, git, github, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

On my github page I have a tab at the top called projects, and I have a bunch of my projects listed there. I created a second tab at the top called initiatives, however I was not able to fill in my initiatives.

Okay so the issue is that _postsi is not defined in _config.yml anyone know how I can do this?

My projects.md calls on my _posts folder (where I have projects listed), and I'm trying to make my initiatives.md call on my _postsi folder (where I have filler initiatives in there)

https://github.com/tusharjoshi1/tusharjoshi1.github.io www.tusharjoshi1.com

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use separate categories for your posts. i.e. you would have your projects and initiatives as separate categories.

```
root
 | -- index.html
 | -- _posts
      | -- projects
           | -- 2014-12-02-Calculating-Molar-Values-Using-VBA.md
           | -- 2015-05-27-Air-Flow-Measurements.md
      | -- initiatives
           | -- 2015-02-13-hamlet-monologue.md
           | -- 2015-02-26-flake-it-till-you-make-it.md
```

Then for your pages you would reference the catetory.

```
{% for poem in site.categories.initiatives %}
  {{ initiative.output }}
{% endfor %}
```

[Here's](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1819) a link that covers this same question for more info.

Also, a little disappointed when I found the Hamlet Monologue.md file didn't include a monologue from Hamlet...  *the play's the thing
Wherein I'll catch the conscience of the King.*

Comment: By categories do I just have to put a folder called projects and initiatives inside _posts? Or is there something I have to change within the config.yml?

Answer (score 0):

After you set the category "initiatives" in your front matter of your post that you want to appear under the tab "initiatives", change you code in initiatives.md to below

```
Currently Being Updated.
<ul>
  {% for post in site.categories['initiatives'] %}
    <div>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
      {{ post.excerpt }}
    <hr>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Note the below line in initiatives.md

> {% for post in site.categories.initiatives %}

should change to

> {% for post in site.categories['initiatives'] %}

Comment: By categories do I just have to put a folder called projects and initiatives inside _posts? Or is there something I have to change within the config.yml?

Comment: I dont think this will work for you. Your front matter in all the posts in your initiatives folder - for eg: 2015-02-13-hamlet-monologue.md has a category called "initiative" and your code in initiatives.md refers to {% for post in site.categories['initiatives'] %}. Either change your category in your post to category: initiatives or change the code in config file to {% for post in site.categories['initiative'] %}